# Rhino - not being able to evaluate javascript with defineClass

Tags: java, javascript, object, rhino

Ok guys coming from this thread [Rhino Evaluating a javascript object in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18565421/rhino-evaluating-a-javascript-object-in-java) I was trying to somewhat evaluate the javascript in a different way. i.e. without the defineClass and its not evaluating the Person object properly.

Can some please help me with this ?

The working code is as follows,

1. Javascript

   ```
   importPackage(Packages.com.testpkg);
   defineClass("com.testpkg.Person");

   var parser = new MyParser();

   var myObject = new Person();
   myObject.string1 = "Hello";
   myObject.string2 = "World";
   myObject.id = 1;
   myObject.string4 = "Testing";
   myObject.string3 = "Another Test";
   try
   {
      var returnStr = parser.PrintObj(myObject);
   }
   catch (e)
   {
      print("An error occured");
   }
   ```
2. Person class

   ```
   public class Person extends ScriptableObject {

      private int id; 
      private String string1;
      private String string2;
      private String string3;

      public Person() {
          System.out.println("Person: Person Constructor");
      }

      public void jsConstructor() {
          System.out.println("Person: jsConstructor");
          this.string1 = "";
          this.string2 = "";
          this.id = 0;
      }

      public int getID() {
          return this.id;
      }

      public void jsSet_id(int value) {
          this.id = value;
      }

      public int jsGet_id() {
          return this.id;
      }

      public String jsGet_string1() {
          return this.string1;
      }

      public void jsSet_string1(String value) {
          this.string1 = value;
      }

      public String jsGet_string2() {
          return this.string2;
      }

      public void jsSet_string2(String value) {
          this.string2 = value;
      }

      public String jsGet_string3() {
          return this.string3;
      }

      public void jsSet_string3(String value) {
          this.string3 = value;
      }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
          return id + " " + string1 + " " + string2 + " " + string3;
      }

      @Override
      public String getClassName() {
          return "Person";
      }

   }
   ```
3. MyParser class

   ```
   public class MyParser {    
       public MyParser() {
           System.out.println("Entered constructor");
       }

       public String PrintObj(ScriptableObject obj) {
           Person pObj = (Person)Context.jsToJava(obj, Person.class);
           System.out.println("Printing p: " + pObj);
           return null;
       }
   }
   ```

The output is,

```
Entered constructor
Person: Person Constructor
Person: jsConstructor
Printing p: 1 Hello World Another Test
```

Now the problem is when I get rid of defineClass. The version of Rhino implemented in an application im using (Rhapsody health product) does not define this method. Hence I cannot use this. I have use an alternative method to load the class Person. If I get rid of defineClass the output will be,

```
Entered constructor
Person: Person Constructor
Printing p: 0 null null null
```

Please help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by following the steps below.

1. Javascript (TestScript.js)

   ```
   Person = com.testpkg.Person;
   MyParser = com.testpkg.MyParser;
   var myObject = Person.getInstance("myObject");
   myObject.id = 1;
   myObject.string1 = "Hello";
   myObject.string2 = "World";
   myObject.string3 = "Another Test";
   myObject.string4 = "Testing";
   try
   {
      var parser = new MyParser();
      var returnStr = parser.PrintObj(myObject);
   }
   catch (e)
   {
      print("An error occured");
   }
   ```
2. Person class

   ```
   package com.testpkg;
   public class Person extends ScriptableObject {

      private int id; 
      private String string1;
      private String string2;
      private String string3;

      public Person() {
      }

      public void jsConstructor() {
          System.out.println("Person: jsConstructor");
          this.id = 0;
          this.string1 = "";
          this.string2 = "";
          this.string3 = "";
      }

      public int jsGet_id() {
          return this.id;
      }

      public void jsSet_id(int value) {
          this.id = value;
      }

      public String jsGet_string1() {
          return this.string1;
      }

      public void jsSet_string1(String value) {
          this.string1 = value;
      }

      public String jsGet_string2() {
          return this.string2;
      }

      public void jsSet_string2(String value) {
          this.string2 = value;
      }

      public String jsGet_string3() {
          return this.string3;
      }

      public void jsSet_string3(String value) {
          this.string3 = value;
      }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
          return id + " " + string1 + " " + string2 + " " + string3;
      }

      @Override
      public String getClassName() {
          return "Person";
      }

      public static Scriptable getInstance(String objectName) throws             IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, InvocationTargetException  {
          Context jsContext = Context.enter();
          Scriptable person = null;
          try {
              ScriptableObject rootScope = jsContext.initStandardObjects();
              ScriptableObject.defineClass(rootScope, Person.class);
              person = jsContext.newObject(rootScope, "Person", null);
              rootScope.put(objectName, rootScope, person);
          }
          finally {
              Context.exit();
          }
          return person;
      }
   }
   ```
3. MyParser class

   ```
   package com.testpkg;
   public class MyParser {    
       public MyParser() {
           System.out.println("Entered MyParser constructor");
       }

       public String PrintObj(ScriptableObject obj) {
           System.out.println("Printing person: " + obj);
           return null;
       }
   }
   ```

So when compile execute like so,

```
java -cp js.jar;MyParser.jar org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main TestScript.js
```

The following output should be displayed,

```
Person: jsConstructor
Entered MyParser constructor
Printing person: Person 1 Hello World Another Test
```

Should be noted that string4 is safely ignored here !